# how to render xml data in blade view

Tags: laravel, rss-reader

I have a serive in root response xml daha as in image below:

```
Route::get('feed', function() {
    $feed = App::make("feed");
    $feed->setCache(60, 'feedNewsKey');
    if (!$feed->isCached()) {
        $news = \DB::table('news')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(20)->get();
        foreach ($news as $post) {
            $feed->add($post->title, 'asd', url('detail/' . $post->id), $post->created_at, $post->description, $post->description,['user_id'=>$post->id, 'photo'=>$post->photo]);
        }
    }
    return $feed->render('atom');
});
```

[image]

I wonder how I can iterate in these xlm data in blade.php view file ?

Comment: Have you looked on [Packagist](https://packagist.org) for libraries to do so? There may be a few that can help you with that (such as [this one](https://packagist.org/packages/sabre/xml) for instance).